# Save-AzureWebSiteLog Invoke-WebRequest error

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, kudu

I was really close to finish my job but it started to cause this error.

when I execute this

```
Save-AzureWebSiteLog -Name $WebSiteName -Output "C:\logs\error.zip"
```

> Save-AzureWebSiteLog : The maximum message size quota for incoming
>   messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the 
>   MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.

so, I searched for the solution, it seems like that many people have exact same problem.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/windows-azure-websites-online-tools-you-should-know-about/

Thanks to @Parth Sehgal, I have tried to solve the problem by using powershell

```
$username = "maiemai"
$password = "Password"
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username,$password)))
$apiUrl = "https://wngphase2it.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zip/LogFiles/"
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $apiUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method GET 
try
{
$filename = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($response.BaseResponse.ResponseUri.OriginalString)
$filepath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine("c:\asdf\", "http1.zip")
$filestream = [System.IO.File]::Create($filepath)
$response.RawContentStream.WriteTo($filestream)
}
finally
{
$filestream.Close()
}
```

but I am stuck with this error

> Invoke-WebRequest : Server Error
>       401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
>       You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
>       At line:5 char:13
>       + $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $apiUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" ...
>       + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>           + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest],
>   WebException
>           + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
>       You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
>       At line:11 char:1
>       + $response.RawContentStream.WriteTo($filestream)
>       + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>           + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>           + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Username and Password is definitely correct, but it is still causing this error.

How should I change this line?

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $apiUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method GET
```

Comment: You're using your deployment credentials for Kudu, not your Azure portal credentials, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your username is incorrect in this case.

In order to use the Azure Kudu REST API to retrieve the zipped log files for your Azure web app, you will need to use your web app's **MSDeploy credential** in the **publish profile** file.

The correct form of Azure web app's MSDeploy username should be **${yoursitename}**.

You can get your web app's publish profile from the new Azure portal or via Azure PowerShell command: `Get-AzureRMWebAppPublishingProfile`

I have also fixed the issue in your PowerShell script which I tested with my own web app.

```
$username = "`$wngphase2it"
$password = "yourMSDeployUserPwd"
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username,$password)))
$apiUrl = "https://wngphase2it.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zip/LogFiles/"
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $apiUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method GET 
try
{
$filename = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($response.BaseResponse.ResponseUri.OriginalString)
$filepath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine("c:\asdf\", "http1.zip")
$filestream = [System.IO.File]::Create($filepath)
$response.RawContentStream.WriteTo($filestream)
}
finally
{
$filestream.Close()
}
```

Reference: [Sample of using Kudu REST API with PowerShell](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API)

Let me know whether it helps to resolve your issue.